# Close Form VBA By Key

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking for a routine that allows me to pick up a key combination such as Ctrl + L to allow me to close a form, all written in VB to someone've already shown how to manage?

Comment: Alt+F4 does this already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a very good question. You're asking users to do the coding for you, not showing an error/attempt that you need work with.

Please learn how to properly ask stackoverflow questions. Please refer to [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

But, to answer:

You're looking for the key down event.

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Control & Keys.L Then
        Form1.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: *tells user off for asking for code, then provides code anyway* Whose side are you on...

Comment: whichever one has the better cookies.